# (SSL Pining) How can a Public Key CA on a Device check the server's certificate

Tags: cryptography, ssl-certificate

How CA on my device check that a digital signature is genuine or fake?. If a hacker gets my digital signature, can they combine my digital signature and their own public key and send the certificate to a client? If so, how can a client know that the certificate does not come from the right server?

Conclusion: I want to know the method of checking the digital signature from Server. How can they use CA's public key checking Digital signature from the Server?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

*Since the first answer, I have updated this further to add further details and clarity.*

**Background on Certificate Authority (CA) & Certificates**

1. Certificate Authorities or CAs issue certificates for individuals or business entities. CAs form a hierarchical structure where at the top, there is Root CA
2. Certificates cannot be tampered by the attackers because the certificates are digitally signed by the certificate issuing CA
3. Root CA has self-signed certificates
4. Root CA signs next-level intermediate CA certificates
5. Root CA certificate and various other globally recognized CA certificates are stored in trusted key store of browsers, operating systems or applications
6. Intermediate CA may issue other intermediate CA certificates creating a chain
7. Certificate chain contains the end certificate to the trusted Root CA including all intermediate CAs in the middle
8. For successful verification of a certificate, the verifying agent must either get the chain certificate from the certificate owner, or,  have the end certificate in its trusted key store

**Digital Signature provides:**

Digital certificates are used to digitally sign documents. The certificate is sent along with the signed document, so that the recipient can verify the authenticity and integrity of the signed document.

Digitally signing a message means computing a hash (one-way) of the message using a pre-defined algorithm and then encrypting the hash with the private key of the certificate owner. since, no-one is supposed to know the private key of the certificate other than the owner himself/herself, no-one else can produce the same signature that can be decrypted with the public key of the certificate.

Digital signature thus provides 3 things:

1. Authentication - By verifying the digital certificate (using the certificate chain as mentioned above), the recipient knows that the message has been indeed sent by a trusted party
2. Non-Repudiation - The message sender cannot deny later that the message was not sent by it, because nobody else has the private key of the message sender and therefore nobody else can sign the message with the same private key
3. Integrity - Since the hash of the received message computed by the recipient is the same as the hash (after decryption using sender's public key) sent by the sender (after decryption using sender's public key), it proves that the client has received the exact same message as sent by the sender, otherwise if the message has been tampered by a deliberate attack or an unintentional network error, the hashes would have been different.

**Digital Signature Creation**
Digital signature is created by

- Computing a hash of the message (that the signature owner wants to send to the other party) using a hashing function
- Encrypting the hash using the private key

**Signature Verification**

Any recipient of a digitally signed document would want to verify the signature to ensure the authenticity and integrity of the document. Verification can be done in the following way:

1. Compute the hash of the message using the same hashing function
2. Decrypt the signature using the public key (available in the certificate) of the sender
3. The computed hash and the decrypted hash should be the same

Therefore as long as the certificate private key is not compromised, it is a robust mechanism.

**Some Technical Details**

Two important standards with respect to certificates are: [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) and [PKCS12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12). The details can be found in the linked Wikipedia pages.

Using the Java `keytool` utility anyone can create a self-signed signature. However, such certificates or signature will not be trusted anywhere unless the recipient add the certificate in their device trust store.

Comment: so the Computing a hash of the message is on client side?, so what message? and how the hash is created? I mean how Computing a hash of the message method relate to CA on a device. I understand that a server side send digital Signature and use public key to get hash and how client  get another hash to compare? I mean client has hash on their device so the hash as we know is trust CA right?

Comment: @LLawliet - added further clarifications in the answer. Hopefully it would clarify the doubts now. Hash is calculated by a mathematical function that takes the message the sender wants to send as an input and outputs a fixed length string. The hash is then encrypted and sent so that an attacker cannot change the meesage, recompute a hash and send to the recipient. So, the hash by itself only provides non-repudiation and integrity. Here CA doesn't come in picture. CA comes when the client/recipient wants to validate that the sender is really the entity that it claims to be.

Comment: Thanks for clarify me but I confused when the recipient get received message to compute hash for comparing hash of sender? Integrity

Comment: @LLawliet, Not sure if I understand your query. Let's say I have a digital signature issued to me by a globally trusted CA. I can sign a pdf document and send it to you. So, you have the message now which is the document. When you open the document in Adobe Reader, you'd see that the document signature is verified provided your device has the CA certificate installed. From SSL perspective, the message is actually a shared secret. You may also want to refer to this answer for SSL related details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53214332/1235935

Comment: Thank for trying to explain me . I just want to know how Recipient get hash for comparing the hash from server, why it would be the same

Comment: Why both hash are the same, client decrypt signature by public key then get hash , where another hash comes from, why it would be the same as server signature hash

Comment: @LLawliet, Let's say I want to send you a document with my signature. I'll use a standard hashing algorithm that takes the document as input and produces a hash as output. I'll encrypt the hash and email you both document and encrypted hash. When you recieve the signed document though email (say), you know the hashing algorithm and you also now have the document. So, you can generate the same hash by feeding the document into the hashing algorithm. If the document hasn't been corrupted or changed deliberately by an attacker, the generated hash will be same as computed by me (the sender)

Comment: So that the answer that I want, if i’m Not wrong, when handshake server sent public key and signature to client. Client decrypt signature by public key and get hash. Client device aleady have CA that contain hash of this server. And compare both hash ,right

Comment: @LLawliet yes that's the basic idea of digital signature. SSL/TLS has ar more things involved in it. You may consider going through the othe answer link I have provided above

Comment: @LLawliet, also if this answers your query, please accept the answer

Comment: so if hacker get my signature and public key by sniffing, mitm or something. and he use it to sent to a client. so the client device would trust hacker's server, right? because it would be the same hash and how cert pinning is useful?

Comment: @LLawliet, if the hacker gets your private key, he can do whatever he wants. So, you need to protect your private key by all means. You are safe as long as your private key is not compromised

Comment: so I might ask the wrong question? so my question is What CA does to verify Digital Signature, how my root CA on my device Verify Signature From Any Server ?

Comment: @LLawliet I may create a self signed certificate claiming that I am Amazon and create a fake ecommerce website. In that case, if you communicate with me, all these hashing, public key, private key will still work as usual. How would you know that I am not the actual Amazon? Real Amazon will have a certificate signed by a globally trusted CA. The CA's certificate is in turn signed by another higher level CA. This chain will go upto Root CA who has a self signed certificate. All these globally trusted CA certificates remain pre-installed in all device operating systems and this allows you to vfy

Comment: ...allows your device to verify that a trusted CA ha signed Amazon's certificate. And CA's do proper background chcks before issueing certificates. So your device knows that this website indeed belongs to the company it claims to be and your browser disaplays the green padlock at the left hand side of the address bar

Comment: and what usually CA certificate look like? Does it contain the server’ public Key or what it use to prove the cerfiticate(digital signature) from server sending?

Comment: I think we are not using the comments in the right way. it looks like a different question. Please post a separate question for that

Comment: OK Thanks For oyour kindness