# what usually CA certificate look like?

Tags: encryption, ssl-certificate

what usually CA certificate look like? Does it contain the server’ public Key or what it use to prove the cerfiticate(digital signature) from server sending?

Comment: You have numerous ones in your browser, take a look at them. Also, your question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53214708/238704) in response to another of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Any certificate contains a public key, which is paired to a private key contained in a private portion of the certificate (i.e., the part that the server has installed but does *not* distribute to clients). This is independent of whether the certificate belongs to a CA or not.

The digital signature will typically belong to a certificate further up in the chain of trust (i.e., the certificate's issuing authority), but if you're looking at a root certificate, it may be self-signed, as those entities are trusted to sign any certificates, even their own.

If you want to look at the contents of any certificate, your browser will let you do that on any HTTPS-based website you visit, typically by clicking somewhere in the address bar. You can search for specific instructions for viewing certificates in just about any major browser. This will let you look at the certificates all throughout the chain of trust, up to the root CA.